# Running Multiple SSIS Data Flow Tasks

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a strange thing happening within an SSIS package which contains many data flow tasks. None of the DF tasks are dependent on each other, though I have tried running them all sequentially to no avail.

All the tasks are similar in nature

1. Select columns A, B, C & J from a table.
2. C# Script Component to convert J (JSON) into Outputs. (Output0, Output1 etc)
3. Insert column A, B, C + J1, J2, J3... into destination table(s).

The difference between the DF tasks are a where statement in step 1 (WHERE A=1), which will return different formatted JSON in column J, so therefore the C# script is different.

I can get each DF task to work flawlessly by right click / execute task, however when I run more than one wierd things happen.

Columns A, B & C are **always** returned correctly, however the contents of Columns J1, J2 etc are usually NULL or incorrectly mapped.

Do you know why this may be and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Do any of these dataflows use package variables at any point?

Comment: yes - but not in the data flow tasks - purely in the onerror event handlers or a SQL task that is run on success.

Comment: Are they all pulling from the same table?

Comment: yes - that is correct, however using different where clauses. DF1 will pull ABCetc WHERE A = 1 and DF2 will pull WHERE A=2

Comment: The more I think about it, though, the less that seems to matter. If there were performance issues, then sure, maybe. But output? Nope. I really thought @TabAlleman was onto something with the variables. You're sure there are none? No parameterized queries? No strings with query text? Nothing passed into the script task, nor coming out of it? I've seen multiple instantiations of the same variable (which you may, in good faith, think is "just" being reused) really squirrel up output.

Comment: Need to see the code for the c# task, specifically the json related bits.  My thoughts are that although they are different tasks, maybe they are using a library in a way that isn't thread safe,

Comment: There are a bunch of parameterised queries, but none which are in the Data Flow task. The DF starts with a stored procedure which takes an argument, but this is passed statically in the Data Source object.

Once the DF has ended there is an execute SQL task which takes the variable value and dynamically inserts it into table. The variable is also used in another Execute SQL task in the on error event handler

Comment: Hmmm... Since the DFTs all work as expected running alone, there pretty much has to be something in the package that's unintentionally sharing a resource between the tasks, and thus causing your pain. @StrayCatDBA may be onto something with the script tasks.

Comment: This won't optimize, but how about setting them to run in precedence if they work individually.

Comment: One other thing - in the Script Component one of the properties SynchronousInputID is set to true. I don't know if that is causing the problem, however if we set it to false I get an error that column names are conflicting.